# How to implement the paginator in Django 2.1?

Tags: django

To product page of my project I need to add paginator. I did according to the Django Documentation but I have the following error:

```
object of type 'InsuranceProducts' has no len()
```

Here is the my views.py:

```
def farmer_types(request, type_id):

    product_areas = InsuranceProducts.objects.filter(product_type="Фермерам")
    product_types = get_object_or_404(InsuranceProducts, id=type_id)

    paginator = Paginator(product_types, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    types = paginator.get_page(page)

    context = {'product_types': product_types,
               'product_areas': product_areas,
               'types': types}
    return render(request, 'insurance_products/farmer/farmer_types.html', context)
```

Here is the my models.py:

```
class InsuranceProducts(models.Model):
    product_area = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.product_area, self.product_type)


class ProductType(models.Model):
    product_area = models.ForeignKey(InsuranceProducts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    body = HTMLField('Content')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.product_area, self.title)
```

Here is the code from the template:

```
{% for product in types.producttype_set.all %}
  <div class="btmspace-80">
    <h3>{{ product.title|upper }}</h3>
    <img class="imgr borderedbox inspace-5" src="{% static 'img/imgr.gif' %}" alt="">
    <p>
        {{ product.description|upper }}
    </p>

    <p>
        Подробно вы можете узнать о новости <a href="{% url 'main:farmer_product' product_types.id product.id %}">здесь</a></a>
    </p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
  <span class="step-links">
    {% if types.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ types.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        Page {{ types.number }} of {{ types.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if types.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ types.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ types.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
   </span>
  </div>

  <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
</div>
```

I did the everything as it is given in the Docs.

Comment: Well you seem to mix two different items: you here first fetch a *single* `InsuranceProducts` object, and then you want to *paginate* that. That is rather strange, since pagination deals with a *collection* of (`InsuraceProducts`) objects.

Comment: The `product_types = get_object_or_404(InsuranceProducts, id=type_id)` fetches (at most) one `InsuranceProducts` object.

Comment: Since you're using Django 2.1 you should look into [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/).

Answer (score 0):

Why is `product_types` plural if you are using `get_object_or_404`, which returns only one object?

You're doing the pagination right, but doing the query wrong. If you change `paginator = Paginator(product_types, 6)` to `paginator = Paginator(product_areas, 6)`, you will see that it works perfectly fine.

You should read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/) on how to do queries, and understand the relationships between models.

Comment: Well, I guess there was some kind of the misunderstanding of quires from my side